# Integrating a 1-10 voting system effectively without common pitfalls

Tags: php, mysql, ranking, bayesian, voting-system

I'm planning on integrating a reasonable ranking/voting system into an existing application.

I'm familiar with how the traditional 5 star rating systems work and know the [common pitfalls/problems](http://www.evanmiller.org/how-not-to-sort-by-average-rating.html) associated with them therefore was wondering if there is other ways (I've heard of Wilsons, Bayesian etc. but not really sure on how to implement this with the below structure):

- I'm planning on allowing users to vote on content between 1 to 10 via the contents page.
- The score and total votes for that content will be displayed on the contents page.
- I will also be displaying/listing the Top 10 Content so I'd need the method to be fair/realistic and not make a vote of 10 with total votes of 1 to go straight to number 1.

I'm using `PHP` and `MySQL`, I have a table for the content (which has a `content_id` which I guess I can `JOIN` on).

I'm wondering if you can suggest a way/method which achieves the above, I'd appreciate if you can attach some example PHP code and example MySQL schema so I can better understand it, as I've google'd and may have found potential solutions such as Wilsons and Bayesian...yet they provide a lengthy article with confusing mathematical equations - and mention no way which achieves the above (ie. the score....and implenting the method in PHP/MySQL) or atleast due to there not being any example PHP/MySQL code me misunderstanding this.

Perhaps this is easier then I think - I don't know as I've never had the need to implement this sort of "more complex" ranking/voting functionality before - so I'd appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 0):

You should start by watching this video on youtube : [Building Web Reputation Systems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yn7e0J9m6rE).

To emphasize the point, let me direct you to [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/937/).

As for DB structure, you need following parts:

- list of items ( with `total_votes` column )
- list of user, which have voted
- intersection table for the items-users ( with `rating` column, if you go with 5star thing )